# Creating a set of sets of objects in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to create a set of set of objects, but am having an error message with how I use the -> with iterator k. I think I have to define some overloaded operators before I use this? I can't seem to find any resources online about my specific problem.

My error message is

```
no instance of overloaded function "std::set<_Kty, _Pr, _Alloc>::insert [with _Kty=Triangles, _Pr=std::less<Triangles>, _Alloc=std::allocator<Triangles>]" matches the argument list and object (the object has type qualifiers that prevent a match)
```

```
std::set<std::set<Triangles>>::iterator k;
for (k = setofTriangles.begin(); k != setofTriangles.end(); k++) {
    double v1query = k -> begin() -> getV1()[1];
    double v2query = k -> begin() -> getV2()[1];
    double v3query = k -> begin() -> getV3()[1];

    double iterYMax = std::max(v1query, std::max(v2query,v3query));             
    if (iterYMax == triangleYMax) {
        k -> insert(addTriangle);
    }
}
```

Please let me know if you need more information. Thank you.

Comment: [mcve] needed.  No mcve, no reasonable way to answer.

Comment: so k -> begin() is an iterator to a set? and how can you call getV1 from a set?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think elements inside a set are mutable since that would interfere with ordering.

Answer (score -1):

When you want to make an stl container in another one, try do it like this, for instance with integers :

```
set<set<int> >
```

You must add a blank space between the last two ">", otherwise the compiler will read it as if it's a writing operator, like

```
cin >> myvariable;
```

Comment: Well i don't know if it's 100% true, but i got a similar problem one day and i managed to avoid the problem by adding the blank space

Comment: If you *"don't know if it's 100% true"*, then do not answer. EDIT: Also, if it worked for you but you don't know why, don't **assume** what compiler does. I'm speaking about *"otherwise the compiler will read it as if it's a writing operator"*

Comment: This is not an answer. Also this is not true since C++11.

Comment: Not true since C++11, but some editors like emacs can get confused. Lexical analysis is non-trivial in C++